# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: undefined. Import error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the next error:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
> it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

I want to invoke child function in the parent component. I tried to use useRef, forwardRef and useImperativeHandle

Parent component:

```
import Tree from '@c-tree'    


const NavTree: FunctionComponent = () => {
  
  const refTree = useRef();

  const tree = () => {
    if (d?.items && status === 'idle') {
      return (
        <Tree onNodeClickCallback={onClick} ref={refTree}>
          {d.items.map(s => (
            <Tree.Asset
              key={s.id}
              name={s.name}
              dataSelected={`${s.id}`}
              item={{
                name: s.name,
                tenantID: s.id,
                type: s?.tree?.name,
                children: [],
              }}
            />
          ))}
        </Tree>
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <SideBar
      title={title}
    >
      <Box display="flex" flexDirection="column" height="100%">
        <StyledBox>{tree()}</StyledBox>
      </Box>
    </SideBar>
  );
};

export default NavTree;
```

Child component:

```
interface TreeStatic {
  Group: typeof TreeGroup;
  Asset: typeof TreeNode;
}

type TreeComponent = ForwardRefExoticComponent<PropsWithRef<ITreeProps>> & TreeStatic;

interface ITreeProps {
  data?: {
    type: string;
    name: string;
    tenantID: number;
    children?: Array<Object>;
  }[];
  ref: any;
}

const Tree = ({
  data,
  ref
}: ITreeProps) => {
  const [contextValues, setContextValues] = useState({
    selected: null,
    opened: {},
  });
 
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    handleCurrentSelected: (selectedName: string) => {
      setContextValues({
      ...contextValues,
      selected: selectedName,
      opened: {
        ...contextValues.opened,
        [selectedName]: !contextValues.opened[selectedName] || false,
      },
    });
  }}
  ));

  return (
    <TreeContext.Provider value={contextValues}>
        {
          React.Children.map(children, child => {
            return React.cloneElement(child, childrenProps);
          })
        }
    </TreeContext.Provider>
  );
};

Tree.Group = TreeGroup;
Tree.Asset = TreeNode;

export default forwardRef(Tree) as TreeComponent;
```

Comment: Can you show us the line where you import `Tree` into the parent component's file?

Comment: import Tree from '@c-tree'
It's import from the npm package

Comment: So the child component is in an npm package? Is that a public package that someone else wrote and you're importing, or is it code that you've written and published? A google search didn't show me any results for an npm package with that name, though you could be using a private npm repository.

Comment: The reason i'm asking these questions is that the bug is almost certainly to do with your imports, not with forwardref/useref/useImparativeHandle.

Comment: I use a private package.

Comment: In that package, what file is the entry point? Ie, if you look in @c-tree's `package.json`, you should see a line that starts with "main", such as "main: "build/index.js,". If the entry point is a different file than the one you showed us for the child component, then we'll need to see that entry point file (at least the part of it that does the exports).

Comment: The child component is the entry point and the main field of package.json has a location to this component.

Comment: In general, I make "export const Tree = ..." and make "import { Tree } from @c-tree" and this helps. Thank you for the clue.

Answer (score 0):

I've made `exported const Tree` and made the next import:

```
import { Tree } from '@c-tree';
```

Old import

```
import Tree from '@c-tree';
```

The problem was in import.